# Search JSON column for JSON that contains a specific value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a postgresql database with a table called choices, in the choices table I have a column called json that contains JSON entries, for example: [1,2,3]

I need a query that returns all entires that contains a specific value.

For example I have the following entries:

- [1,2,3] [6,7,1] [4,5,2]

I want to get all entries that contain the value 1 so it would return:
[1,2,3]
[6,7,1]

Thanks,

Comment: Simple regexp '[1]'?

Comment: By "entries" do you mean rows/records? And please remove mysql tag since this is about postgres only.

Comment: I mean a specific field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7c26a984cb75d0c4721038b2b38c1705)

The `json_array_elements_text`functions expands the json arrays into one row each element (as text). With that you can filter it by any value you like.

```
SELECT 
    json_data
FROM choices, json_array_elements_text(json_data) elem
WHERE value = '1'
```

[Documentation: JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

---

Please notice that "json" is a the name for the json type in PostgreSQL. You should better rename your column to avoid some conflicts. (I called mine `json_data`)